# How to loop each row separately?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

[I have two rows that I would like to loop for each row. I have start month and end month, and would like to output each month in between the two months but also including them for each row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i0ub.png)

My desired output would be:

```
[[7,8,9,10,11,12], [7,8,9,10,11,12],[7,8,9,10,11,12], [9,10,11,12], [11,12]... etc
```

Any Idea on how to do so? Sorry for the confusion, I am new to python.

Comment: Please include table and code as text (and not as an image) in your question. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Check out the [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
list(map(lambda x : list(range(x[0], x[1]+1)), df[['StartMonth','EndMonth']].values))
```

`df` is the Pandas DataFrame of your table.